# Ruby on Rails: Change the JSON from a form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, forms, dynamic, jsonb

I have 0 experience with jsonb, so apologies if this is a basic question.
I managed to get my dynamic form built and submit to the database, but I would like to
change the format that the data is getting to the database. I'm using Postgres and my "status" field is jsonb.

With my form design its storing the data like:

```
{
     "9" => "23",
    "11" => "1",
    "13" => "1",
    "14" => "1",
    "18" => "32"
}
```

I would like the data to be stored in the following maner:

```
[
  {
    id: "9"
    value: "23"
  },
  {
    id: "13"
    value: "23"
  }
]
```

My Model:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :client_unit, optional: true
  belongs_to :industry, optional: true
end
```

My form:

```
<div class="row">
  <% schema = JSON.parse @client.schema %>
  <%= form_for @client, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :status, OpenStruct.new(@client.status) do |df| %>
      <% schema.each do |initiative| %>
        <div class="card card-block col-6">
          <div class='card-header bg-primary text-light'>
            <h5><%= initiative['name'] %></h5>
            <small> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <i class="fas fa-sm fa-info-circle"></i> </small>
          </div>
          <div class='card-body'>
            <div class='form-group'>
              <% initiative['milestones'].each do |milestone| %>
                <% if milestone['category'] == 'Boolean' %>
                  <div class='custom-control custom-checkbox pt-2' style='padding-left: -30px; padding-bottom: 0px'>
                    <%= df.check_box milestone["id"], class: 'custom-control-input', include_hidden: false%>
                    <%= df.label milestone['id'], milestone['name'], class: 'custom-control-label' %>
                    <%= check_box_tag 'status[value]', true %> ###### <-- This is me trying stuff out
                  </div>
                <% else %>
                  <div class='input-group input-group-sm pt-2'>
                      <%= df.text_field milestone["id"], class: 'form-control', style: 'max-width: 45px' %>
                    <label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 3px"><%= milestone['name'] %></label>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
            <small style="padding-bottom: 10px;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <i class="fas fa-sm fa-info-circle text-primary"></i> </small>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='card-footer'>
      <%= button_to :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass arrays in Rails (and Rack in general) as formdata you want to use empty brackets in the keys:

```
irb(main):019:0> qs = "client[milestones][][id]=9&client[milestones][][value]=23&client[milestones][][id]=13&client[milestones][][value]=23"
irb(main):020:0> p = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(qs)
=> {"client"=>{"milestones"=>[{"id"=>"9", "value"=>"23"}, {"id"=>"13", "value"=>"23"}]}}
```

You can use `fields_for` to setup nested inputs possibly by using a struct as the model. I'm not really sure what to actually make of that form as there is way to much insanity going on. In absolutely no situation should you be doing stuff like JSON parsing in the view.

I have a strong feeling you're missing some key domain objects.

To whitelist an array of hashes pass a hash key with an array of permitted attributes:

```
irb(main):005:0> params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"client"=>{"mileston
es"=>[{"id"=>"9", "value"=>"23", "id\n    "=>"13"}, {"value"=>"23"}]}})
irb(main):006:0> params.require(:client).permit(:foo, :bar, milestones: [:id, :v
alue])
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"milestones"=>[<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"9", "value"=>"23"} permitted: true>, <ActionController::Parameters {"value"=>"23"} permitted: true>]} permitted: true>
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks for the help on the subject and to teach how to test it on IRB, helped a lot. I was able to get the data to parse the way I wanted to the database. It works!